# USB Event Log when computer powered down

Tags: usb, event-log

I had a GoPro stolen from my computer at my work desk last night (I'm assuming). The GoPro was connected to one of my USB ports, and I was wondering if Windows tracked that information somehow? I have already tried using USBDeview, but the last known time it had for "Plug/Unplug" was when I plugged it in that morning.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is maybe.

Look at this [article](http://dfstream.blogspot.com/2014/01/the-windows-7-event-log-and-usb-device.html).  Windows does record some USB dis/connection events, but not all.  There is no guarantee the information you are looking for is there though.